# Declaring enum in function signature as return status

Tags: c, enums, language-lawyer, return-value

I recently came up with what I assume is an odd way of declaring a function return status in c-code. A function performing a task often returns a status code depending on success or error. This is often sent as an integer or an enumeration declared somewhere else in the file (or another file). I found that by declaring the enum in the function signature we can:

- Have the possible return values close to the function signature
- Have a unique set of return values for each function, avoiding unused values

E.g. like this:

```
// implementation.h
enum {
    OK,
    INTERNAL_ERROR,
    NO_PARAMETERS
} do_that();

// implementation.c
enum {
    OK,
    INTERNAL_ERROR,
    NO_PARAMETERS
} do_that() {
    if (this())
        return OK;
    else if (that())
        return NO_PARAMETERS;
    return INTERNAL_ERROR;
}
```

I have never seen anyone use this style; is it valid? If not, why not?

One downside I see is that you have to state the possible return values in both the c-file and header file, but this also makes it more available and clear directly when you look at the signature.

Another issue is that as far as I understand implicit conversion between enum-types are allowed even in pedantic c, that means that declaring different return states in the function declaration and implementation (c and h file) will not generate a warning or error.

Comment: Why not a typedef?

Comment: With which compiler do you compile this code? [gcc](https://tio.run/#c-gcc) is not happy because of redefinitions...

Comment: Even if the enumerator values are identical, I'm not convinced this is legal C. If the enumerator values differ in any way then it certainly isn't which makes the technique useless. That said though, it's an interesting question if the values are identical such as you present.

Comment: @Closers: how the deuce is this opinion based?

Comment: Each file is independently valid and usable.  What you can't do is include `implementation.h` in `implementation.c` — which means you lose the cross-checking that headers normally provide.

Comment: @Bathsheba My guess is because it was asking for pros and cons of a particular programming style. That is an off-topic subject because what people consider pros/cons is often opinion-based. I've edited the question to remove that language and reflect what's really being discussed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major problem is that you can't use the compiler to cross-check the header and the implementation because the implementation TU (translation unit) — that is, `implementation.c` in the question — cannot include the header (`implementation.h`) because the enumeration constants would be doubly defined, which isn't allowed.  That means the compiler can't spot inconsistencies between the provider and consumers of the service.  The consumers can use the header, but the provider (`implementation.c`) cannot.

Also, only one function can use `OK` (or `INTERNAL_ERROR` or `NO_PARAMETERS`) — other functions need different names for the 'no error' status, and different names for each of the error statuses.  Consequently, it isn't a practical solution for even small-scale software, even though it can be used for a single function (but it isn't a good idea to do so).

Incidentally, note that although there are declarations for `do_that()`, there is no prototype for it in either the header or the implementation file.  The function is declared to take an indeterminate list of parameters — all that's known is that it is not formally a variadic function (no ellipsis `...`), and all of its arguments are subject to the [default argument promotion](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) rules (roughly: `char` and `short` are promoted to `int`; `float` is promoted to `double`).  If the function takes no arguments it should be written as `do_that(void)` so that there is a prototype available after the declaration is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Trying:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// implementation.h
enum {
    OK,
    INTERNAL_ERROR,
    NO_PARAMETERS
} do_that();

// implementation.c
enum {
    OK,
    INTERNAL_ERROR,
    NO_PARAMETERS
} do_that() {
    if (mytest == 0)
        return OK;
    else if (mytest == 1)
        return NO_PARAMETERS;
    return INTERNAL_ERROR;
}

int main() 
{ 
    printf("do_that(%d) = %d\n",0,do_that(0));
    printf("do_that(%d) = %d\n",1,do_that(1));
    printf("do_that(%d) = %d\n",2,do_that(2));
    return 0; 
}
```

Gives:

```
Main.c:11:5: error: redefinition of enumerator 'OK'
    OK,
    ^
Main.c:4:5: note: previous definition is here
    OK,
```

So you can't:

- include your .h in the .c.
- declare the function prototype

Why don't you just use a typedef?